# Rewriting $(e^b-1)(\frac{b/n}{e^{b/n}-1})$ and $(e^b-1)(e^{b/n})(\frac{b/n}{e^{b/n}-1})$ so that I can take the infimum and supremum

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, supremum-and-infimum

So I made an underapproximation and overapproximation for a sum and got that the underapprox is $(e^b-1)(\frac{b/n}{e^{b/n}-1})$ and the overapprox is $(e^b-1)(e^{b/n})(\frac{b/n}{e^{b/n}-1})$.
Now I want to rewrite those so that I can take the supremum of the underapprox and infimum of the overapprox. So for the underapprox I want to find something that is less than or equal to $(e^b-1)(\frac{b/n}{e^{b/n}-1})$ and for example we know that exp(x) $\ge$ 1+x but does that help me here? It would become $(b)(\frac{b/n}{e^{b/n}-1})$ I guess because I don't want to use it on the exp term in the denominator.

Ohh, and we also know that exp(x) $\le$ $\frac{1}{1-x}$

Comment: Send the sum, too.

Comment: Good question, decently explained, +1.

Comment: @Raffaele the sum is P   =   { ( x ,   y )   ∈   ℝ ^2   |   0   ≤   y   <   e^x   and   0   ≤   x   <   b }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As $n\to\infty$ we have

$(e^b-1)\left(\frac{b/n}{e^{b/n}-1}\right)< e^b-1$

and

$(e^b-1)(e^{b/n})\left(\frac{b/n}{e^{b/n}-1}\right)>e^b-1$

because $$\underset{x\to 0}{\text{lim}}\;\frac{x}{e^x-1}=1$$

Actually the sum is $$\int_0^b e^x \, dx=e^b-1$$